# Universal-Image-Loader how to fitcenter in ImageView

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

load image in imageview from url, image display scaletype fitcenter after few second image automatically resize.

```
imageLoader.displayImage(url, ivSingleWallpaper, options,
            new ImageLoadingListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    // Utils.showProgress(getActivity());
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                        FailReason failReason) {
                    // Utils.closeProgress();
                    // Utils.showToast(getActivity(),
                    // failReason.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                        Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    // Utils.closeProgress();
                    ivSingleWallpaper.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
                    // Utils.closeProgress();
                }
            });
```

how can set fitcenter in imageview.

Comment: Try out picasso: http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Picasso.with(context).load(url).fit().into(ivSingleWallpaper);

Comment: i think scaletype is property of imageview.add scaletype to imageview in xml file and enjoy..!

Comment: @Imtiyaz It doesn't change the resized image even with the `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`. Any other way?